# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on images after switch to HTTPS

Tags: 8, redirection, .htaccess, ssl

I have the Drupal 8 site was working with HTTP on the port 80. I switched it to HTTPS with port 443. I got the problem for ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when accessing some images from physicals path.

For example path: https://www.example.com/theme/sites/basic/img/fileimage.png

It happened on some files which are display on the pages. I tried access other files on the same level folder "img" is working. (i.e img/logo.png)

I guess it's cache problem. Here what I did:
 - Clear cache
 - Drush cr
 - Deleted some special table within cache_ inside.
 - I stop mysqld, it's still happened.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

From my admin/config/Basic Site Setting. I still saw

```
Default front page: http://www.example.com
```

It should be https? How I can resolve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Drupal 8 I fixed it by change

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]
```

to

```
# if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
# you don't bounce between http and https.
RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out** -

```
# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It's not working, I think possible on cache issue.